# Cell line break changes table layout

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables, tablelayout

I have a table with a fixed width. Here the last two rows should always be without breaks. However, the table layout is changed if another cell has more content and therefore has to wrap.

I've already played with word-break and nested spans, but without success. It's quite strange, but I hope the following code helps to clarify the situation:

```css
:root {
  --color-background: whitesmoke;
  --color-pageBox: #666;
  --color-paper: white;
  --color-marginBox: transparent;
  --main-bg-color: #943126;
  --main-accent-color: #1C2833;
  --line-height: 1.28rem;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  font-kerning: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  line-height: var(--line-height);
}

table {
  width: 702px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--line-height) * 1.2);
}

table th {
  background-color: var(--main-accent-color);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--color-paper);
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

table td {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

table td.bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}

table td.code {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

table td.small {
  font-size: .8rem;
  line-height: .8rem;
}

table.table-params th:first-child {
  width: 25%;
}

table th:last-child:not(:only-of-type) {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  border-left: 1mm solid var(--color-paper);
}

table th:last-child {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

table th:last-child span {
  float: right;
  font-weight: 600;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ececec;
}

table tr {
  border-left: 0;
}

table a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-params">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="4">Value<span>AS2</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">URL</td>
      <td colspan="4" style="user-select: all">https://example.com:8443</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Certificate subject</td>
      <td class="code small" colspan="4"><span>This is a short subject which fits in one line </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Certificate serial</td>
      <td class="code" colspan="4">11:22:33:44:55:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oftp-feature" style="border-bottom: 0.5mm solid var(--main-accent-color);">
      <td width="25%" class="bold">Delivery Notification</td>
      <td class="bold">File&nbsp;encryption</td>
      <td class="bold">File&nbsp;signing</td>
      <td class="bold">MDN&nbsp;signing</td>
      <td class="bold">Content-Type&nbsp;(preferred)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sync or async</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>application/octet-stream</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table-params">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="4">Value<span>AS2</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">URL</td>
      <td colspan="4" style="user-select: all">https://example.com:8443</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Certificate subject</td>
      <td class="code small" colspan="4"><span>This is the exact same table but with a long subject which does not fit in one line </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Certificate serial</td>
      <td class="code" colspan="4">11:22:33:44:55:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oftp-feature" style="border-bottom: 0.5mm solid var(--main-accent-color);">
      <td width="25%" class="bold">Delivery Notification</td>
      <td class="bold">File&nbsp;encryption</td>
      <td class="bold">File&nbsp;signing</td>
      <td class="bold">MDN&nbsp;signing</td>
      <td class="bold">Content-Type&nbsp;(preferred)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sync or async</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>application/octet-stream</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add the [table-layout](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.php) property via css so that it always renders the same widths etc. After that the first table also wraps the last "Content-Type..." column. I also added a `white-space: nowrap` via a dummy `ff` class. Your table is simply to small for that content, cause now it overflows to the right.

```css
:root {
  --color-background: whitesmoke;
  --color-pageBox: #666;
  --color-paper: white;
  --color-marginBox: transparent;
  --main-bg-color: #943126;
  --main-accent-color: #1C2833;
  --line-height: 1.28rem;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  -ms-hyphens: auto;
  -webkit-hyphens: auto;
  -moz-hyphens: auto;
  hyphens: auto;
  font-kerning: normal;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  line-height: var(--line-height);
}

table {
  width: 702px;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.ff {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

table:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: calc(var(--line-height) * 1.2);
}

table th {
  background-color: var(--main-accent-color);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--color-paper);
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

table td {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

table td.bold {
  font-weight: 600;
}

table td.code {
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}

table td.small {
  font-size: .8rem;
  line-height: .8rem;
}

table.table-params th:first-child {
  width: 25%;
}

table th:last-child:not(:only-of-type) {
  background-color: var(--main-bg-color);
  border-left: 1mm solid var(--color-paper);
}

table th:last-child {
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

table th:last-child span {
  float: right;
  font-weight: 600;
}

table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #ececec;
}

table tr {
  border-left: 0;
}

table a {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-params">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="4">Value<span>AS2</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">URL</td>
      <td colspan="4" style="user-select: all">https://example.com:8443</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Certificate subject</td>
      <td class="code small" colspan="4"><span>This is a short subject which fits in one line </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Certificate serial</td>
      <td class="code" colspan="4">11:22:33:44:55:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oftp-feature" style="border-bottom: 0.5mm solid var(--main-accent-color);">
      <td width="25%" class="bold">Delivery Notification</td>
      <td class="bold">File&nbsp;encryption</td>
      <td class="bold">File&nbsp;signing</td>
      <td class="bold">MDN&nbsp;signing</td>
      <td class="bold">Content-Type&nbsp;(preferred)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sync or async</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>application/octet-stream</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table class="table-params">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th colspan="4">Value<span>AS2</span></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">URL</td>
      <td colspan="4" style="user-select: all">https://example.com:8443</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Certificate subject</td>
      <td class="code small" colspan="4"><span>This is the exact same table but with a long subject which does not fit in one line </span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="bold">Certificate serial</td>
      <td class="code" colspan="4">11:22:33:44:55:AA:BB:CC:DD:EE</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="oftp-feature" style="border-bottom: 0.5mm solid var(--main-accent-color);">
      <td width="25%" class="bold">Delivery Notification</td>
      <td class="bold">File&nbsp;encryption</td>
      <td class="bold">File&nbsp;signing</td>
      <td class="bold">MDN&nbsp;signing</td>
      <td class="bold">Content-Type&nbsp;(preferred)</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Sync or async</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>Yes (any)</td>
      <td>application/octet-stream</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for that swift reply. I tend not to agree with your statement that the table is too small. It is, if using fixed table layout, because those last columns are rendered wider than needed.

Comment: @ToastStudios it is due to the `.ff` class which I added on the last column "Content-Type (preferred)" (setting `nowrap`), not due to the fixed table layout. I updated the snippet and removed that class.

Comment: Thank you @zangab for pointing on nowrap. The lines break at the whitespaces, so you can make use of the [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.php) property. The used class "oftp-feature" already existed, so I selected the last 4 children in tr:


`table.table-params tr.oftp-feature td:nth-last-child(-n+4) {
    white-space: nowrap;
}`
The code now works, without the use of `table-layout: fixed;`